# how to manage frequent and complex poco changes to database structure

Tags: c#, .net, json, entity-framework

In order to tackle the constant changes to a poco class that we have, we are serializing our poco into json string and then storing them into nvarchar column in our sql database.

However,  we are finding this approach difficult to manage. when structure changed, we have to manually alter the json string so that the json serializer can deserialized it again.

Does anyone has a good solution to this problem?

Should we drop the json idea and start storing the poco in the similar fashion as other pocos we have using code first and manage changes with sql script to update databse columns

Comment: Have you considered using EF code-first migrations? I would have thought that trying to serialize data to JSON removes most of the benefits of using a SQL database and probably creates as many problems as it solves. What about one of the many No-SQL document databases?

Comment: Consider whether an EAV model would be right for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497153/can-entityframework-support-an-eav-model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your approach and use a feature that is native to SQL Server: use an [XML column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190936%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) instead of a nvarchar column. This XML column can be used in the same way as your nvarchar column (it will contain object properties serialised to XML instead of JSON), **and it is queryable using SQL**. You could use the [standard XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to obtain the XML to store in the column or write your own simple XML serialisation engine to pick and choose exactly which properties to serialise and how.

When you extract (retrieve) the column data you can quite simply deserialise it back into your data objects in a very generic and forgiving way (i.e. each node in the serialised XML would represent a property on the target object - just iterate this and use reflection).

This approach is very useful when storing disparate objects or frequently changing objects into the same table, and can also be considered to be a close approximation to having a [multivalued](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MultiValue) [database](https://www.google.com/search?q=multivalue%20database%20vs%20relational%20database&revid=694789458&sa=X) structure.