# Code first add properties at runtime

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am using entity framework code fisrt lets say this is my classes:

```
public class Class1
{
    public string property1{get;set;}
    public string property2{get;set;}
}
```

I have a requirement to implement that the user can add "dynamic properties" to my entity framework code first classes **but without changing the model and droping the database!** does it make sense? how would you implement this requirement? It is really important to me to understand it because in my **real model I have maybe 30 classes** and I want to understand what the best strategy to implement it or to say to my customers that 
this requirement is too hard and not reliable to implement.

Comment: Watch out! This is a very pervasive requirement! What you're describing here is an EAV model (Entity Attribute Value). It's not trivial (but doable) to implement this. If this requirement is in the category "nice to have" try to solve it by adding some fixed "anonymous" properties (like `Property01, Property02, ...`) and assign a caption at runtime. Not nice either, but less work. But in the end, maybe this is just a call to better normalization of your model.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497153/can-entityframework-support-an-eav-model

Comment: Are you looking for something like Azure Mobile Services Table where you can change table on runtime, add, remove columns as you need? (dynamic schema)

Comment: Yes something like that

Answer (score 1):

You could create one `String` property in table and JSON serialize custom object that contains "dynamic" properties in it.

--

```
public class Class1
{
    public string property1{get;set;}
    public string property2{get;set;}
    public string CustomProperties { get; set; }
}
```

Then in code you have some dictionary or whatever where you specify property name and it's value:

```
Dictionary<string, object> customProperties;
```

After you fill those properties with "dynamic" data, you just serialize it to string (using JSON, XML, etc) and save ti to CustomProperties field in table.

So when you need to read those properties you just deserialize it and read value you need.

Comment: can you explain your answer I didn't understand