# Fluent API one to many mapping without navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Since we keep adding more and more properties to entities we decided instead of using tables for each type to use a generic new property called IdContainer which contains a set of properties.

In fluent API Configuring One to Many is very easy, but I am having some trouble here.

Usually, when having navigation properties on both sides I would so something like:

```
builder.Entity<Entity>(e => e
    .HasMany(m => m.Properties)
    .WithRequired(m => m.Entity)
    .HasForeignKey(f => f.IdContainer)
```

But this case is different because there is no navigation property as it can be linked to many different types of entities.

[image: MAPPING]

In reality there is also another table called Container which only contains an Identity column IdContainer. The only purpose of the table is for generating a new ID to associate entities with their containers.

So my question is how can map the properties to the specific entities so that I can access them in a fashion similar to:

```
Entity.Properties.FirstOrDefault().Name;
```

Also, with this code the website goes up, but when trying to add a property like this:

```
Entity.Properties.Add(new Property{
    IdContainer = Entity.IdContainer.Value,
    IdProperty = IdProperty
});
```

I get an null reference error after attaching to db and saving, but solved this by just inserting it directly instead of adding it like this.

Comment: I think you may be (reasking?) .. "can EF support EAV?"      See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497153/can-entityframework-support-an-eav-model